# HTACCESS - redirecting all index.html to / - REGEX help understanding

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

This rule will force any index.html to 301 redirect to /:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html[^\ ]*\ HTTP/

RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

I'm looking for help understanding exactly what this match is doing (e.g. regexp help!).

Some specific questions:

1) `%{THE_REQUEST}` - why is this needed?

2) HTTP/ - what is this for?

3) `index\.html[^\ ]*\`  - this means after the index.html there can't be a \ or a space, right?

Any input would be greatly appreciated in helping me understand this regex.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, undone. I'm new here and learning the ways! appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

## 1)

The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is the first line of the HTTP request. It typically looks something like this:

- `GET /some/dir/file.html HTTP/1.1`
- `HEAD /images/some-image.png HTTP/1.0`
- `POST /form/submit.php HTTP/1.1`

This is significant because the variable doesn't change and is literally what is requested by the client/browser, unlike variables like `%{REQUEST_URI}` or `%{QUERY_STRING}` which change each iteration the rewrite engine runs through your rules. So as the rewrite engine processes your rules, you know for certain that the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is exactly what the browser requested, and not what the current iteration of the request or query string is.

## 2)

The `HTTP/` matches the version part of the request. There's actually an older type of HTTP request where the version part is dropped entirely (a "short" GET), but for most intents and purposes, it indicates the end of the requested URI + any query string parameters. Example:

- `GET /some/path/script.php?a=1&b=2 HTTP/1.1`

The  `HTTP/` indicates the end of the URI path + parameters: `/some/path/script.php?a=1&b=2`.

## 3)

The `[^\ ]*` matches anything *except* a space. The `\` is an escape character that is used to escape the space. Otherwise, mod_rewrite will assume the space means the end of the regex and the start of any flags; ultimately, resulting in an error.

The regex `index\.html[^\ ]*` in particular matches `index.html` plus everything that could possibly come after it except a space. So:

- `index.html`
- `index.html?some=param&and=more`
- `index.html/some/path/`

would all match that regex. The purpose of the regex is that you just want to match whatever is after `index.html` that is part of the requested URI path + params, and then the  `HTTP/` which comes after the URI. You don't care what it is, just match against it if there's anything there.